# Google drive changes native file (workspace apps files) binaries just by opening the file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

Body

I need help with https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/revisions export links
I had one observation about the export links and needed to know the root cause for the behaviour

The resource at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/revisions has a property exportlinks
It helps to download a file created by google workspace app

The observation which I had is that - Even though I don't edit a file lets say docx file, infact I just opened/closed the file the metadata of the file resource changes which is fine but the binaries which I download from revisions export links also change. The concern is when I don't edit a file why would the binaries get changed?